# How to set textview from another thread

Tags: multithreading, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to set a textview's text from other thread than the main one,so I've written in the constructor:

```
    Thread myth = new Thread (new ThreadStart (set_txt));
    myth.Start ();
```

and of course set_txt is a method contains

```
    textview1.Buffer.Text = "Whatever";
```

The probleme is that When I run the code most time it stops and gives an error:

```
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

What should I do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the GTK# text view from the GUI thread. You can do this by using Gtk.Application.Invoke:

```
 Gtk.Application.Invoke (delegate {
     textview1.Buffer.Text = "Whatever";
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the UI from the UI thread. Just use `Gtk.Application.Invoke` passing it a lambda or a delegate:

```
Gtk.Application.Invoke(() => { textview1.Buffer.Text = "Whatever"; });
```